# Git newbie: files from a folder are being removed

Tags: git, directory-structure

I'm new to git and I've got a problem with my assets files. I'm developing on a branch called "development", and I have a master branch.
Now I've got 2 folder containing assets (one (www/assets/) in which I upload images,videos,... depending on the needs of our customer - and it also contains subfolders (for example: www/assets/images/icons, www/assets/images/profilepics or www/assets/videos), and one in which I put images purely for the design of the site.
When I push or merge my branches they clear out these folders. How can I prevend git from doing so?

my gitignore looks like this:

```
.DS_Store
.idea/workspace.xml
www/images
www/assets/
```

and

```
git status --ignored

Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    www/assets/images/
    www/images/
```

Comment: You need both folders to be ignored?

Comment: 1. In your code snippet of your .gitignore, you're ignoring `www/images`. In your description text you mention the path as `www/assets/images`
2. If you ignoring the folders, the files will not be include in your commits

Comment: To keep things simple you would have to create a separate folder for site assets - which include icons, images used on the site, and the public assets  uploaded by the end users. And you can ignore the public assets checked into your repo, by ignoring them from .gitignore file.

Comment: I guess I haven't explained myself that well:
I want the files in www/assets and all of its subfolders, and in www/images intact after pushing/merging, that might be the easiest way to explain it :-)